# How to track changes in directory without saving using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, events

I have a directory which contains several sub-directories and files. I want to track changes in files without save.

> means when there is any character added or deleted in file, It must be
>   tracked before pressing CTRL+S or save in every 5 seconds

```
Note: I have tried several solutions but all are fine for saved files.
```

Comment: If changes are not saved, then the file has not changed. Don't think there is any way to track that without being inside whatever code is making changes to files.

Comment: I thought that there may be possible solution for it.